# Multiple inner JOIN on the same table

Tags: mysql, query

I have this table 'individu'

[image: individu table]

and this table

[image: lien table]

I want to do a select and get in the query, the 'nom' and 'prenom' for iid1 and iid2.

For the moment my query is

```
SELECT * FROM lien 
inner join individu on individu.id = iid1 
WHERE individu.famille_id = 1002 
AND iid1 = 1
```

But with that I only got the iid1's name

Comment: For clarity, can you edit your question and add examples of the expected output? Also, as I understand it, you need all rows from individual where they have an id in either iid1 or iid2. Is that correct?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is maybe what you want based on what I understood from the tables:

```
SELECT a.famille_id, 
      a.iid1,
      b.prenom prenom1,
      b.nom nom1,
      a.iid2,
      c.prenom prenom2,
      c.nom nom2
FROM lien a
left join individu b on b.id = iid1 and b.famille_id  = a.famille_id 
left join individu c on c.id = iid2 and c.famille_id  = a.famille_id 
where b.famille_id = c.famille_id
```